# Polyglot persistence for startup app

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, zeromq, apache-kafka, polyglot-persistance

I'm in the process of developing my next app, and I'm really interested in using polyglot persistence. I like the idea of being able to query different data structures for different services. I'm essentially wanting to sync MongoDB, Neo4j/Titan, SQL, and maybe Cassandra/Hbase.

Currently, I'm wrapping everything in a try/catch block and rolling them all back if one fails. However, this is taxing my write times. I've also looked into AMQP systems like Kafka or ZeroMQ, but these seem more big data centric, whereas my app is still small and I want to keep it efficient.

Has anyone had experience with this? Is a MQ a good idea for a small app or am I prematurely optimizing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know quite a bit about ZeroMQ, but not a lot about the database servers you mention.

First, you're a bit confused about ZeroMQ. Although it is derived from experience with AMQP, it uses the ZMTP wire protocol. That was custom designed during ZeroMQ development [but other applications do now use it].

ZeroMQ is a small and very fast MQ library that is symmetrical for all nodes; it is very good for small apps. The problem here is that you need something on the other systems that talks ZMTP, whether it's ZeroMQ or a bridge. If you intend making plugins or the like for the other systems then fine.

I presume though, that you are using JMS to talk to the other systems without intending to develop add-ons for them. In which case you're probably stuck with JMS. Kafka is a new one that I haven't caught up with, but RabbitMQ is a good, fast, and small, broker. FWIW. There are a great many broker comparisons out there for you to find. Many are dodgy in the sense that one small tweak of a setting can affect the performance greatly and are not necessarily comparing apples with apples. If want to compare broker performance in your environment, there isn't much of a shortcut to doing it yourself.

One thing that is confusing me is how you expect a broker to help your rollback performance. You'll still need to do the rollback in essentially the same manner, albeit asyncronously via the broker.

Comment: Hey thanks, does rabbitmq offer a more common protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I work at CloudBoost.io (https://www.cloudboost.io) and we build a layer that sits on top of databases and give you the power of Polyglot Persistence persistence. We integrate MongoDB, ElasticSearch, Redis, Cassandra, and Neo4j and give you the one single APIwhere you can query / store your data. We automatically shard your data into various databases based on your query / storage request patterns.

Let me know if this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

For syncing data from MongoDB to Neo4j there is now the [Neo4j Doc Manager](http://neo4j.com/developer/mongodb/#_neo4j_doc_manager) project. It works by monitoring MongoDB for operations and converts the document operation into a property graph model and immediately writes to Neo4j.